# How do I make a directory on a windows 2008 shared over the internet?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I wan't to install a software on my Windows 2008 R2 vServer and make a certain directory accessible (read, write, change) for client workstations.

What is the best practice for this?

thx in advance

Comment: Use the built in file and folder sharing in Windows, probably.  Of course, you don't want to do this "over the internet" or you'll basically be sharing those files with the whole world.  Of course, it's not exactly clear if you really mean "over the internet" or "over my private LAN," which makes a big difference.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to expose a SMB file-share over the Internet, you need to open port 445 on your firewall and share it just like you would on your internal network.

This is a really really **bad** idea, though. What you should really do is set up a VPN for your remote clients and have them VPN into your private network to access these resources.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Could you further explain the VPN Solution please? Are VPN functions built in or do I need additional solutions like openVPN?

Comment: You can use RRAS to set up a VPN if you'd like. Read the documentation for it, try it, test it, and then come back if you need help with a *specific* piece of it. Just saying `"Could you further explain the VPN Solution please?"` is insulting. It implies that you don't want to put the effort in to doing any research yourself.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. I needed a starting point for a further research and RRAS is such a starting point.

Comment: +1 for the REALLY BAD IDEA.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be WebDAV with AD authentication, over HTTPS. But WebDAV client support is iffy, depending on the client. So, Sharepoint might be a good bet.